# AutoMapper ValueFactory attempted to access the Value property error when deployed to server and after executing fine for few days

Tags: c#, automapper, webapi

I created this web application using Automapper for DTO mappings and it works fine locally and also when deployed to server initially for some time. But after some days it throws below error and the site stops functioning. I read most of the threads on StackOverflow but I couldn't find a solution. Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Automapper version: 6.2.2.0

Error location:

details = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map>(headerDetails);

Log

{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"ValueFactory attempted to access the Value property of this instance.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":" at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()\r\n at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()\r\n at AutoMapper.Mappers.ConvertMapper.MapExpression(IConfigurationProvider configurationProvider, ProfileMap profileMap, PropertyMap propertyMap, Expression sourceExpression, Expression destExpression, Expression contextExpression)\r\n at AutoMapper.Execution.ExpressionBuilder.MapExpression(IConfigurationProvider configurationProvider, ProfileMap profileMap, TypePair typePair, Expression sourceParameter, Expression contextParameter, PropertyMap propertyMap, Expression destinationParameter)\r\n at AutoMapper.Execution.TypeMapPlanBuilder.CreatePropertyMapFunc(PropertyMap propertyMap, Expression destination)\r\n at AutoMapper.Execution.TypeMapPlanBuilder.TryPropertyMap(PropertyMap propertyMap)\r\n at AutoMapper.Execution.TypeMapPlanBuilder.CreateAssignmentFunc(Expression destinationFunc, Boolean constructorMapping)\r\n at AutoMapper.Execution.TypeMapPlanBuilder.CreateMapperLambda(Stack`1 typeMapsPath)\r\n at AutoMapper.TypeMap.Seal(IConfigurationProvider configurationProvider, Stack`1 typeMapsPath)\r\n at AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration.ResolveTypeMap(TypePair typePair, ITypeMapConfiguration inlineConfiguration)\r\n at AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration.ResolveTypeMap(TypePair typePair)\r\n at AutoMapper.Execution.ExpressionBuilder.MapExpression(IConfigurationProvider configurationProvider, ProfileMap profileMap, TypePair typePair, Expression sourceParameter, Expression contextParameter, PropertyMap propertyMap, Expression destinationParameter)\r\n at AutoMapper.Mappers.Internal.CollectionMapperExpressionFactory.MapItemExpr(IConfigurationProvider configurationProvider, ProfileMap profileMap, Type sourceType, Type destType, Expression contextParam, ParameterExpression& itemParam)\r\n at AutoMapper.Mappers.Internal.CollectionMapperExpressionFactory.MapCollectionExpression(IConfigurationProvider configurationProvider, ProfileMap profileMap, PropertyMap propertyMap, Expression sourceExpression, Expression destExpression, Expression contextExpression, Type ifInterfaceType, MapItem mapItem)\r\n at AutoMapper.Mappers.CollectionMapper.MapExpression(IConfigurationProvider configurationProvider, ProfileMap profileMap, PropertyMap propertyMap, Expression sourceExpression, Expression destExpression, Expression contextExpression)\r\n at AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration.GenerateObjectMapperExpression(MapRequest mapRequest, IObjectMapper mapperToUse, MapperConfiguration mapperConfiguration)\r\n at AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration.BuildExecutionPlan(MapRequest mapRequest)\r\n at AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration.CreateMapperFuncs(MapRequest mapRequest)\r\n at AutoMapper.LockingConcurrentDictionary`2.<>c__DisplayClass2_1.<.ctor>b__1()\r\n at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()\r\n at AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration.GetUntypedMapperFunc(MapRequest mapRequest)\r\n at AutoMapper.Mapper.AutoMapper.IMapper.Map[TDestination](Object source)\r\n at RockyBrands.EDISettings.Core.EDI865ControlTable.EDI865Service.GetAllControlTableHeaderDetails(String ediDocType, String tradingPartner, String customerCode) in C:\\Development\\Rocky_EDISettings_New\\Rocky_EDISettings\\Dev\\Source\\RockyBrands.EDISettings\\Application Tier\\Business Layer\\RockyBrands.EDISettings.Core\\EDI865ControlTable\\EDI865Service.cs:line 534\r\n at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"}

Comment: You best bet is to upgrade. Other than that, try setting `CreateMissingTypeMaps` to false.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am wondering why this happens in this project while other projects has the same version works fine.

Comment: Of course it's something about that particular mapping. Feel free to investigate :) A recursive mapping of some sort.

Comment: I will try to upgrade the version and see. This only happens after executing without any issues for few days(sometimes works fine for several weeks). That's why its hard to find a solution.